# How to make Universal Apps for windows

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have migrated an application from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and now I wish to make the app adaptive to all windows devices.To do this I can either use Visual state triggers in XAML or my preferred choice, page size change function in C# to respond to the change in window size. But when using this code you have to specify the pixel width and height you want the code to respond to. As we all know there are different versions of laptops with different pixel heights and widths. So when I target one specific pixel width and height I have noticed when I run the app on another laptop with a different pixel width and height icons and buttons are out of place. So in essence my question is when making Universal apps does windows expect you to target each particular device not just the type but the width and height too when designing the screens? Or is there a way to target all pixels and widths of a device type when designing so that icons and buttons are not out of place?

Comment: [This is quite a good site to read that dictates how to do suitable design in a UWP application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different options to make your UI adaptable. You can use an option exclusively or a combination of them.

1. Visual states and state triggers - one XAML file across all device families but the XAML can quickly become unwieldy for complex XAML
2. Separate XAML views per device family - Use XAML views to create different UI definitions that share the same code-behind. You can provide a unique UI definition for each device family.
3. Separate XAML pages per device family - To provide unique views and functionality, you can create separate Page files (XAML and code), and then navigate to the appropriate page when the page is needed.

You can read about these approaches in detail here [Define page layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml#separate-xaml-views-per-device-family)